# ISNULL MIN together

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, min, isnull

Good morning folks. I have had a good search but cant quite find an answer (or one I can understand)

I have a stored Procedure and would like to return a date as part of the query, however if there is no record (NULL) then return something friendly like 'No Planned Stock'

I have this

```
ISNULL(MIN(wt.CompletionDate),'No Planned Stock') AS NextStockIn
```

This results in the following error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

BUT this half works (is there such a thing as half works?)

```
MIN(ISNULL(wt.CompletionDate,'No Planned Stock')) AS NextStockIn
```

The issue with this is that I still get NULL instead of 'No Planned Stock'

In an Ideal world id like a nicley formatted (dd/MM/yyyy) date or 'No Planned Stock'

I would really appreciate any help on this, thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm surprised that works at all. if you're storing `wt.CompletionDate` as a `date`/`datetime` then the literal string `'No Planned Stock'` is going to be implicitly converted to a `date`/`datetime`. Obviously, `'No Planned Stock'` is not a date. I suggest returning a `NULL` to your presentation layer and changing the `NULL` value there. otherwise you'll have to `CONVERT` the value of `wt.CompletionDate` to a `varchar`, and that means you lose the datatype (which could cause other problems).

Comment: Further to my comments above, formatting of data (like dates to `dd/MM/yyyy`) is something that should most definitely be done in the presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks Larnu In the presentation layer im using "=IIF(((ReportItems!Textbox72.Value) < 0) ,Fields!NextStockIn.Value,"")" the idea is to only return this value when running stock drops below 0.  Could I do this here? (any help would be greatly appreciated)

Comment: I'm *assuming* that's an SSRS expression. A date with a value of `NULL` doesn't have a value less than 0, so that expression will never be true. The correct expression for your textbox would likely be something like: `=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!CompletionDate.Value) = False,Fields!CompletionDate.Value,"No Planned Stock")`. Then you'd need to set the format of your textbox as well. You do so by selecting the textbox and pressing `F4`. Then in the Properties Pane locate the Format Property, and change it to `dd/MM/yyyy`. The formatting **won't** error on the value `"No Planned Stock"`.

Comment: That is an SSRS expression the <0 is referring to another textbox in the report "running value" so when the stock "running value" falls below 0 then the date is displayed or ideally 'No Stock planned'  im trying to modify your expression suggestion to look at the running value too... fingers crossed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking about these ways

```
CASE WHEN CAST(wt.CompletionDate AS VARCHAR(25)) IS NULL 
THEN 'No Planned Stock' 
ELSE CAST(MIN(wt.CompletionDate) AS VARCHAR(25))
```

Because varchar is certainly not a compatible with datetime type, but sometimes, depending on the value of varchar data, it could be convertible to datetime type automatically by SQL Server, which in this case 'No Planned Stock' isn't convertible to datetime value.

Or maybe you can also try this one

```
ISNULL(CAST(MIN(wt.CompletionDate) AS VARCHAR(25)),'No Planned Stock') AS NextStockIn
```

I haven't test these, but I hope this works as expected

Comment: ISNULL(CAST(MIN(wt.CompletionDate) AS VARCHAR(25)),'No Planned Stock') AS NextStockIn    is working!! the cherry on the cake would be to make it look a little nicer  so 15/03/2018 at the moment its March 15 2018 12:00AM

Comment: I am glad, you can use FORMAT() for the display on the date after MIN() function on the query, so it would be like CAST(FORMAT(MIN(...)))